Problema de confirmacion de Orden
Estoy haciendo un microservicio con Springboot y otras herramientas , me problema surje al mandar el emial donde estoy utilizando el MailDev
Cuando ejecuto el programa anda todo bien excepto que una de las funciones de notificacion , es mandar una orden de confirmacion pero no me llega:
El error :

java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process
'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an
'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
Caused by:
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.RecordDeserializationException: Error
deserializing key/value for partition order-topic-0 at offset 0. If
needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by:
org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException:
failed to resolve class name. Class not found
[com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.OrderConfirmation]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.OrderConfirmation

Mi codigo : 
package com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.order;

import com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.payment.PaymentMethod;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.List;

public record OrderConfirmation(
        String orderReference,
        BigDecimal totalAmount,
        PaymentMethod paymentMethod,
        Customer customer,
        List<Product> products

) {
}

  kafka:
    consumer:
      bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
      group-id: paymentGroup,orderGroup
      auto-offset-reset: earliest
      key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
      value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer
      properties:
        spring.json.trusted.packages: '*'
        spring.json.type.mapping: orderConfirmation:com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.order.OrderConfirmation,paymentConfirmation:com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.payment.PaymentConfirmation


Hola Lautaro, si te lees todo el mensaje de error, te encontrarás con la frase: **Class not found [com.lautaro.ecommerce.kafka.OrderConfirmation] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **, esta indica que no encuentra la bendita clase, comprueba que la misma esta en el paquete correspondiente, y si lo esta, edita tu pregunta, y agrega el arbol de directorios de tu aplicación, para ver si detectamos el error.
